# Ethercalc not launching on Docker and c9.io

Tags: node.js, docker, c9.io

Whenever i am trying to launch ethercalc using docker or c9.io(ubuntu instance). It is not working and throwing an error as shown below. But it is running locally without any issues in Mac.

```
ethercalc
Please connect to: http://a36thninja-ether-4985966:8080/
Starting backend using webworker-threads
/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js:31
            compile: [(...args) => this._convertDataImages(...args)],
                       ^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:373:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.__dirname.include (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/emailer.js:13:18)
    at Object.context.include (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/node_modules/zappajs/lib/zappa.js:581:26)
    at Object.__dirname.include (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/sc.js:214:20)
    at Object.context.include (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/node_modules/zappajs/lib/zappa.js:581:26)
    at Object.__dirname.include (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/main.js:17:15)
    at Object.context.include (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/node_modules/zappajs/lib/zappa.js:581:26)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/app.js:58:17)
    at Object.zappa.app (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/node_modules/zappajs/lib/zappa.js:875:10)
    at zappa.run (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/node_modules/zappajs/lib/zappa.js:1024:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/app.js:49:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/app.js:60:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/.nvm/versions/node/v4.6.1/lib/node_modules/ethercalc/bin/ethercalc:7:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:441:10)
    at startup (node.js:139:18)
    at node.js:974:3
```

Is it some thing related to port binding or IP binding in those platforms or anything related to dependencies?

Comment: Please include the Dockerfile and full `docker run` command that you are running to get this output.